# R missing value. There are two data set, at the same ID, CUSIP & DATE, one is fine for its data, another has NA. How to fit it by Complete database?

Tags: r, missing-data

There are two data set, A & B, as below

A

```
id  CUSIP  name  day 
  01  00256  ALEX  20170101
  02  00259  BEAR  20170101
  03  00258  CAT   20170101
```

B

```
  id  CUSIP  name  day
  01  00256  NA    20170101
  06  00259  BEAR  20170106
  09  00258  CAT   20170109
```

There is an `NA` in data set B, but we can see at the same CUSIP the name's column of A data set is not an `NA`, it is `ALEX`.

How can I use the data in the A database to fill the B database under the same CUSIP? So as to make the whole thing like below:

B

```
id  CUSIP  name  day
  01  00256  ALEX  20170101
  06  00259  BEAR  20170106
  09  00258  CAT   20170109
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information above:

```
 A=data.frame(id=c(01,02,03), CUSIP=c(00256,00259 ,00258 ),
         name=c("ALEX","BEAR","CAT") ,day=c("2017-01-01" , "2017-01-01","2017-01-01")
         ,stringsAsFactors = F)

 B=data.frame(id=c(01,06,09),CUSIP=c(00256,00259 ,00258 ), 
         name=c(NA,"BEAR","CAT"),day=c("2017-01-01" ,  "2017-01-06","2017-01-09"),
         stringsAsFactors = F)
```

To be able to fill B using A :

```
dplyr::coalesce(B,A)
  id CUSIP name        day
1  1   256 ALEX 2017-01-01
2  6   259 BEAR 2017-01-06
3  9   258  CAT 2017-01-09
```

Answer (score 1):

```
B$name <- ifelse(is.na(B$name), A$name[match(A$id, B$id)], B$name)
```